# How to make 360 video output in opengl

Tags: opengl, shader, panoramas, 360-degrees

i want to have OpenGL output with spherical projection for make 360 video.

now i have cube map faces and they are generated with 6 perspective cameras.

i need something like this :
[image]

how can i have this output?

any idea?

Answer (score 2):

It depends on the exact projection you are expected to use. For a simple spherical projection you render a quad into your destination texture with the following fragment shader:

```
uniform samplerCube tex;
in vec2 texcoord;
out vec4 OUT;

void main() {
    vec3 d = vec3(
        cos(texcoord[0])*cos(texcoord[1]),
        sin(texcoord[0])*cos(texcoord[1]),
        sin(texcoord[1])
    );
    OUT = texture(tex, d);
}
```

`texcoord` shall vary between `(-tau/2,-tau/4)` in bottom left corner and `(tau/2, tau/4)` in top right corner.

Comment: Thanks @ybungalobill ,your solution was really helpful but that was not exactly what i want, i finally found it here :[ShaderToy](https://www.shadertoy.com/view/XsBSDR) , anyway thank you for your helpful answer.

Comment: It's the same thing.