# Render 360 videos in Direct2D

Tags: c++, winapi, direct2d, 360-degrees

I'm looking to import 360 videos into my video sequencer with the ability to change the view port at runtime.

For sample, I downloaded this vimeo video: https://vimeo.com/215984568.

As far as I understand technically, this is a common H264/H265 format which reads as such in my application already:

[image]

So as I get it, it's all a point of which area to render and how to transform it.

1. Is there a Source Reader interface that can handle the transform ? All I could find is the MediaPlayer UWP example (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/audio-video-camera/play-audio-and-video-with-mediaplayer) which does not render manually.
2. If not, is there some protocol that explains the methods of rendering of such videos? I found this OpenGL-based (https://medium.com/@hanton.yang/how-to-create-a-360-video-player-with-opengl-es-3-0-and-glkit-360-3f29a9cfac88) which I could try to understand if there isn't something easier.
3. Is there a hint in the MP4 file that it should be rendered as 3D ?

I also found [How to make 360 video output in opengl](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44082298/how-to-make-360-video-output-in-opengl) which has a shader that I can port to Direct2D.

I know the question is a big vague perhaps, but couldn't find any usable C++ code so far.

Comment: If you need to edit the frames, on your MediaPlayer link, specifically check out the FrameServer mode option. This should provide you with Surfaces you can use in Direct2D to do what you need, though if you just need to account for the spherical mapping and that's it,  you can configure this object on MediaPlayer PlaybackSession https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.media.playback.mediaplaybacksphericalvideoprojection?view=winrt-19041

Comment: Note MediaPlayer is marked as DualApiPartition so it's not limited to UWP. You can use it from a Win32 desktop app using WinRT C++ projections. But it's not Direct2D, ok.